# C# dll method call fails to write and read to/from the registry when called from ASP.NET web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, registry

I have a class within a dll that has the following methods for writing to the registry:

```
public Boolean WriteDBConnectionInfoToRegistry(string txtDSN, string txtServer, string txtDatabase, string txtUser, string txtPassword, bool trusted)
        {
            SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
            rijn.GenerateKey();
            rijn.GenerateIV();
            Boolean b1 = RegistryWrite("Software\\MyApp", "IV", Reverse(Convert.ToBase64String(rijn.IV)));
            Boolean b2 = RegistryWrite("Software\\MyApp", "Key", Reverse(Convert.ToBase64String(rijn.Key)));
            Boolean b3 = RegistryWrite("Software\\MyApp", "DSN", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Reverse(txtDSN))));
            Boolean b4 = RegistryWrite("Software\\MyApp", "Server", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Reverse(txtServer))));
            Boolean b5 = RegistryWrite("Software\\MyApp", "Database", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Reverse(txtDatabase))));
            Boolean b6 = RegistryWrite("Software\\MyApp", "User", EncryptString(Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Reverse(txtUser))),rijn.IV,rijn.Key));
            Boolean b7 = RegistryWrite("Software\\MyApp", "Password", EncryptString(Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Reverse(txtPassword))), rijn.IV, rijn.Key));
            Boolean b8 = RegistryWrite("Software\\MyApp", "Trusted", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Reverse(trusted ? "1" : "0"))));

            if (b1 && b2 && b3 && b4 & b5 & b6 & b7 & b8)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


  private bool RegistryWrite(string subKey, string KeyName, object Value)
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
                RegistryKey sk1 = rk.CreateSubKey(subKey);
                sk1.SetValue(KeyName.ToUpper(), Value);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The methods are contained within a public class, that is part of a dll that I have installed in a ASP.NET web page. The methods successfully write to the registry when called from a Windows application to test, however when the method is called from the code behind in the web site, it fails to write to create the folder and keys, despite returning true. How can I fix this? The framework for the .dll is .Net 2.0 and the web application is in 4.0. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The ASP.NET runtime is a "partial trust" environment, so that even if your site gets hacked, a piggybacking attacker can't do as much damage. Registry changes usually require not only full trust, but running the application that makes them with elevated permissions. Can't speak for why it looks like it worked, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I'd change your catch block to include some kind of logging when errors occurs.  Also your code changes from using && to &; that looks like a typo.  Finally, check the permissions assigned to the application pool's account and ensure UAC is not enabled.

Comment: Do you know how I can set the permissions to the needed level? Or direct me to an explanation of how to do so?

Comment: The permissions are already set to "needed level", the problem is that you trying to do something that you should not be doing. Please consider another approach that does not require running web site code elevated OR giving web application write access to registry. I.e. have setup script to configure DB connection the same way for all servers serving the same application.