# Process does not have permission to Write to the Windows Registry

Tags: .net, dll, registry

I am using the demo version of the PDFTron DLL which I'm using to test with in my .Net web application running though IIS. Unfortunately I need to do this in the live environment and am receiving the following error messages...

```
    The evaluation version encountered an error in your system configuration. 
    To learn more see this web page: http://www.pdftron.com/kb_eval_error 
    Process does not have permission to Write to the Windows Registry
```

Having read links that the pdftron site gives out and the following stackoverflow post I am still no wiser as to what I need to do to get the dll working.

[C# dll method call fails to write and read to/from the registry when called from ASP.NET web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631235/c-sharp-dll-method-call-fails-to-write-and-read-to-from-the-registry-when-called)

I have attempted changing the webconfig file to add a "trust" level of "full" but this does not work.

```
<trust level="Full" />
```

Can anyone tell me where I need to make the changes so I can test this software out on the live server environment please even if it is only once that I test the features out so the business I work for can evaluate the cost per year/benefit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to IIS Manager, select the web server, and then to Application Pools.
2. Click on the application pool you are using from the list, then on the Actions panel, under Edit Application Pool, click Advanced Settings...
3. In the Advanced Settings dialog, go to the Process Model section and click on the Identity to change it.
4. Once the Application Pool Identity dialog shows up, select Custom account:, then click Set...
5. Enter the user account information in the Set Credentials dialog box. Note: you may have to specify the domain of the user (i.e. MyServerDomain\MyUserAccount).
6. Click OK until all dialog boxes are closed.